# Odd behavior in C++/SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been working on a game in C++/SDL, but I am very puzzled by why my program is closing before the "while" loop ends. I looked for any loopholes, but came out empty-handed. However, after experimenting with the program, I suspect that the culprit is in my "menu.h" file. Here is all the code in the game. Player.h is just a bunch of definitions so far.

include_file.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_FILE_H_INCLUDED
#define INCLUDE_FILE_H_INCLUDED

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>

using namespace std;

struct image_struct
{
    SDL_Surface *donkey;
    SDL_Surface *donkey_select;

    SDL_Surface *kawasaki;
    SDL_Surface *kawasaki_select;

    SDL_Surface *desert;
    SDL_Surface *desert_select;
};

struct sound_struct
{
    Mix_Music *menu_theme;
};

struct clip_struct
{
    SDL_Rect level_select[1];
    SDL_Rect player_select[1];
    SDL_Rect bike_select[1];
};

void applysurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination, SDL_Rect    *source_clip = NULL)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;

    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(source, source_clip, destination, &offset);
};

int quit;
string level;

image_struct image;
sound_struct sound;
clip_struct clip;

SDL_Surface *screen;
SDL_Event event;

void variable_setvalue(void)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    Mix_OpenAudio(22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096);

    clip.level_select[0].x = 0;
    clip.level_select[0].y = 0;
    clip.level_select[0].w = 128;
    clip.level_select[0].h = 128;

    clip.level_select[1].x = 128;
    clip.level_select[1].y = 0;
    clip.level_select[1].w = 256;
    clip.level_select[1].h = 128;

    clip.player_select[0].x = 0;
    clip.player_select[0].y = 0;
    clip.player_select[0].w = 50;
    clip.player_select[0].h = 100;

    clip.player_select[1].x = 50;
    clip.player_select[1].y = 0;
    clip.player_select[1].w = 100;
    clip.player_select[1].h = 100;

    clip.bike_select[0].x = 0;
    clip.bike_select[0].y = 0;
    clip.bike_select[0].w = 100;
    clip.bike_select[0].h = 50;

    clip.bike_select[1].x = 0;
    clip.bike_select[1].y = 50;
    clip.bike_select[1].w = 100;
    clip.bike_select[1].h = 100;

    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(512, 512, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    image.donkey = IMG_Load("images/donkey.png");
    image.donkey_select = IMG_Load("images/donkey_select.png");

    image.kawasaki = IMG_Load("images/kawasaki.png");
    image.kawasaki_select = IMG_Load("images/kawasaki_select.png");

    image.desert = IMG_Load("images/desert.png");
    image.desert_select = IMG_Load("images/desert_select.png");

    sound.menu_theme = Mix_LoadMUS("sounds/death_desert_racing.wav");

    level = "desert";
    quit = 0;

};


#endif // INCLUDE_FILE_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include "include_file.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "menu.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    variable_setvalue();

    while (quit == 0)
    {
        menu_action();
        if (level == "desert")
        {
            SDL_WM_SetCaption("Death Desert Racing", NULL);
        };
    };

    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    Mix_CloseAudio();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
};
```

menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H_INCLUDED
#define MENU_H_INCLUDED

#include "include_file.h"
#include "player.h"

struct menu_struct
{
    int desert_x;
    int desert_y;
    int donkey_x;
    int donkey_y;
    int kawasaki_x;
    int kawasaki_y;

    SDL_Rect *desert;
    SDL_Rect *donkey;
    SDL_Rect *kawasaki;
};

menu_struct menu;

void menu_action(void)
{
    SDL_Event menu_event;

    string level_select = "desert";
    string character_select = "donkey";
    string vehical_select = "kawasaki";

    menu.desert = &clip.level_select[0];
    menu.donkey = &clip.player_select[0];
    menu.kawasaki = &clip.bike_select[0];

    menu.desert_x = 0;
    menu.desert_y = 0;

    menu.donkey_x = 0;
    menu.donkey_y = 0;

    menu.kawasaki_x = 0;
    menu.kawasaki_y = 0;

    int menu_number = 0;
    int done = 0;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (done == 0)
    {
        while (menu_number == 0)
        {
            if(SDL_PollEvent(&menu_event))
            {
                x = menu_event.motion.x;
                y = menu_event.motion.y;

                switch(menu_event.type)
                {
                    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                        if ((x > menu.desert_x) and (x < menu.desert_x + 128) and (y > menu.desert_y) and (y < menu.desert_y + 128))
                        {menu.desert = &clip.level_select[1];}
                        else {menu.desert = &clip.level_select[0];};
                        break;
                };
            };

    applysurface(menu.desert_x,menu.desert_y,image.desert_select,screen,menu.desert);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    };
        while (menu_number == 1)
        {
            if(SDL_PollEvent(&menu_event))
            {
                x = menu_event.motion.x;
                y = menu_event.motion.y;

                switch(menu_event.type)
                {
                    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                        if ((x > menu.donkey_x) and (x < menu.donkey_x + 128) and (y > menu.donkey_y) and (y < menu.donkey_y + 128))
                        {menu.donkey = &clip.player_select[1];}
                        else {menu.donkey = &clip.player_select[0];};
                        break;
                };


            applysurface(menu.donkey_x,menu.donkey_y,image.donkey,screen,menu.donkey);
            SDL_Flip(screen);
            };
        };
    };
};

#endif // MENU_H_INCLUDED
```

EDIT: I received these messages after step through debugging.

```
#0 6812A21B SDL_Flip() (e:\projects\death_desert_racing\bin\debug\SDL.dll:??)
#1 00401748 menu_action() (E:/Projects/Death_Desert_Racing/menu.h:69)
#2 004019BD SDL_main(argc=1, argv=0x9e0750)   (E:\Projects\Death_Desert_Racing\main.cpp:11)
#3 00402887 console_main(argc=1, argv=0x9e0750) (./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:315)
#4 00402944 WinMain(hInst=0x400000, hPrev=0x0, szCmdLine=0x241f22 "", sw=10) (./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:398)
#5 0040205A main(argc=1746172080, argv=0x68134e90, __p__environ=0x68134540   <SDL_RegisterApp+15408>) (../mingw/main.c:73)
```

Comment: Why do you think culprit resides in `menu.h`? What does your investigation of the problem reveal? Have you used a Debugger & stepped through and tried debugging?

Comment: I put "SDL_WM_SetCaption" right before "menu_action" in main.cpp and it displayed the caption right before the window closed. I was fast enough to see that the caption change from "SDL_APP" to "death_desert_racing." I removed the line of code in the post.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger? It will help you pinpoint where the problem might be, and maybe even show you exactly what the problem might be.

Comment: from what I observed: clip_struct in include_file.h has three members, which are arrays with each one element. But in variable_setvalue you seem to access them as if they are arrays with two members. Doesn't seem like a good idea to me

Comment: I finally figured out what Joachim was talking about, and the debugger points right to menu.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm answering my own question, but I FINALLY figured it out! So I used Joachim's tip about the step through debugger, then it said that there was an error that said:
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." So, I looked up what that meant, at www.unix.com/programming/27967-program-received-signal-sigsegv-segmentation-fault.html. So I looked carefully at where SDL_Surface screen was declared and assigned a value. Turns out, in "include_file.h", inside of variable_setvalue(), I accidentally put "SDL_Surface *" before screen, which meant that the very first time I used SDL_Flip(screen)(which was in "menu.h" in "menu_action()") the program crashed by closing right away without freezing.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make a link, so the link is not available for now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that @John nailed it and deserves credit for the answer.  When you start assigning values to `clip.level_select[1].x` you've just started unintentionally squashing memory belonging to other variables.  The actual result is probably compiler dependent, but it's not unlikely that you somehow change the `quit` variable in the process.  Try changing the variable declarations:

```
struct clip_struct
{
    SDL_Rect level_select[2];
    SDL_Rect player_select[2];
    SDL_Rect bike_select[2];
};
```

And see what happens.

Comment: The same thing happened. There was absolutely no change whatsoever. I seriously suspect that the problem is within the menu.h file.

Comment: But chances are this is another problem that hasn't come up yet.